# @Autowired gives null in RequestInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        log.info("[RequestInterceptor] Request received is:" + request.toString());
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = authHeader.split(Constants.authorizationPrefix)[1];
        log.info("token:" + token);
//      JwtUtils jwtUtils = new JwtUtils();
        DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtUtils.decode(token);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

And then this is JwtUtils:

```
@Service
@Component
public class JwtUtils {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

private final Request request;
private final Environment environment;

@Autowired
public JwtUtils(Request request, Environment environment) {
    this.request = request;
    this.environment = environment;
}
public DecodedJwt decode(String token) { //decode here }
```

}

I have added `@Autowired` on top of `Request` class. And `Environment` class is from  `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`

When I debug, `jwtUtils` in `RequestInterceptor` is `null`.

What could be possible cause of this??

I tried injecting fields and not using constructor, but it still didn't work.

When I remove `@Service` and `@Component` from `JwtUtils`, I can use `new` operator to use `JwtUtils` in `RequestInterceptor`, but in that case the fields that are `utowired in`JwtUtils`-`Request`and`Environment`- become`null`.

Case 2:
When I use `JwtUtils` in some other class with the `@Service` and `@Component`, there are no issues with it.

And this is how RequestInterceptor is registered

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried the question that is marked here for duplicate and mentioned in the answer that methods suggested there are not working.

Comment: How did you registered RequestInterceptor ?? using `new` operator or `@Autowired`??

Comment: Added in question. Using new operator.

Comment: It should be autowired like `@Autowired RequestInterceptor interceptor; @Override
     public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
     }`

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! Works.